# cambiar doble comillas ""por punto y coma ; en php

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

tengo este archivo en C:\xampp\htdocs\products.csv y necesito reemplazar la doble comilla con tab por punto y coma, el archivo tiene ya permiso de escritura

En el archivo original esta así: **"Modelo1"    "Modelo2"   "Modelo3"**

y lo necesito así: **Modelo1;Modelo2;Modelo3**

pensaba reemplazar esto: (" ") por esto (;) con el siguiente código

```
<?php
$path_to_file = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\products.csv';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
$file_contents = str_replace("" "",",;",$file_contents);
file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents);
?>
```

esto solo funcionaria para las dobles comillas separadas por un tab ("  ") luego me quedarían las dobles comillas solas de los extremos las cuales reemplazaría por (campo vacío) con este codigo

```
$file_contents = str_replace("""",",",$file_contents);
```

convirtiendo este archivo en un csv separado por punto y coma (;) quedando algo como esto:
**Modelo1;Modelo2;Modelo3**

pero me da error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '""' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

como las " es carácter reservado para la función en php no se como reemplazar he probado comillas simples   ' y tampoco funciona.

he realizado esto

esta perfecto por que cambia a ; pero tengo este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como hago para borrar el NUL

Comment: probá escapear `"\"\""` o usar comillas simples `'"'`

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y completa la pregunta para poder ayudarte mejor. Sin ver el contexto es imposible saber de dónde viene el `NULL`. Y, dado que es un archivo, pon en la pregunta unas cuantas líneas de tu archivo, o una captura de pantalla con el visor de caracteres ocultos activados.

Answer (score 1):

No soy experto en REGEX, pero con [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match-all.php) puedes obtener un grupo de los valores entre comillas, sin importar nada lo que haya antes o después. Me parece una solución más robusta, porque no depende de si antes o después hay espacios, tabulaciones, etc.

Luego, con el array de las capturas, puedes usar `implode` para crear tu cadena separada por `;`, por `,` o por lo que quieras. Como complemento, si quieres, puedes pasarle un `trim()` a cada elemento del array, para limpiar posibles espacios en blanco que pueden estar rodando al principio o al final, como suele ocurrir en este tipo de datos.

Un ejemplo sencillo, con una cadena complicada a propósito:

```
$str='"   Modelo1" "Modelo2   " " Modelo3 "';

$out="";
if (preg_match_all('~(["\'])([^"\']+)\1~', $str, $arr)){
    $out .= implode(";", array_map("trim", $arr[2]));
}
echo $out;
```

**Salida:**

```
Modelo1;Modelo2;Modelo3
```

La ventaja de hacerlo así, aparte de que simplificas todo, es que funcionaría, aunque los valores vengan así:

```
$str='"Modelo1" gñsakñlsak "Modelo2" dsñlkdñsg "Modelo3"';
```

O aunque vengan dispares:

```
$str='"Modelo1" "Modelo3"';
```

Porque el REGEX se centra en buscar los valores que hay entre comillas.

**PD:**

Como dije antes, no soy experto en REGEX, pero es posible que incluso con un solo REGEX puedas incluso hacer el reemplazo sin necesidad de usar `implode`. Si algún experto en REGEX pasa por aquí quizá podría ilustrarnos al respecto. Para ello te recomendaría que pongas la etiqueta REGEX a tu pregunta.

Comment: vale lo he probado si  funciona pero lo veo en pantalla la finalidad es que reemplace el archivo que esta en esa ruta, no tengo idea de como reemplazarlo

Comment: @IvanDiazPerez simplemente tienes que hacerlo como está en tu código, la línea que escribe en el archivo es esta: `file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents);`, entonces, haciendo algo así, debería escribirlo: **`file_put_contents($path_to_file,$out);`** Solamente he cambiado la variable (`$out`) asumiendo que ahí están los datos reemplazados correctamente.

Comment: lo habia probado pero me sale por cada letra un NULL MNULLoNULLdNULLeNULLlNULLo

Comment: @IvanDiazPerez si es un archivo puede que haya más cosas en ese archivo y si el archivo tiene varias líneas con valores como `"Modelo1" "Modelo2" "Modelo3"` tienes que aplicar el código de la respuesta **en cada línea del archivo**. ¿Es posible que falte contexto en tu pregunta? ¿Estás leyendo un archivo línea por línea queriendo reemplazar cada línea?

Comment: si el archivo tiene 100 lineas y esta en C:\xampp\htdocs\products.csv

Comment: @IvanDiazPerez pues lo dicho, sería cuestión de aplicar el código de la respuesta, `preg_match_all` e `implode` a cada línea, en el bucle de lectura, ir guardando todo en `$out` y fuera del bucle escribir `$out` en el archivo.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119421/discussion-between-ivan-diaz-perez-and-a-cedano).

Comment: he editado la pregunta abajo muestro un resultado ya convierte a ; solo me queda eliminar el NUL